# How to achieve strong typing as demonstrated by Bjarne Stroustrup during his latest talk?

Tags: c++, strong-typing

During Bjarne Stroustrup's [latest talk](https://youtu.be/fX2W3nNjJIo?t=53m22s) he talks about strong typing.

Specifically a custom datatype `milliseconds` is used instead of `int`.

How is this achieved?

Further, would this mean that such datatypes would have explicit / implicit conversions? For example from `meters` to `millimetres`? How could this be achieved?

Apologies if this seems trivial - I am a C++ novice but find this feature very useful

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/operator%22%22ms is an example of assigning a time interval attribute (ms) to an interval. Very nice feature of C++ 14

Comment: Are there similar concepts for distance, weight and money? This is so that functions which expect pounds cannot take kilos etc

Comment: Boost has a unit library: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_1/doc/html/boost_units.html

Comment: Make a class to encapsulate the type, and implement cast operators to handle conversions.

Comment: fluent c++ blog has a series of articles explaning how to implement strong types https://www.fluentcpp.com/2016/12/08/strong-types-for-strong-interfaces/